# Passing variable from @Controller to @ControllerAdvice in SpringMVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I created `@ControllerAdvice` that has to set me some model attribute.

```
@ModelAttribute
public void globalAttributes(Model model) {
       model.addAttribute("pageId", PAGE_ID);
}
```

This is a generic example of what I need, and PAGE_ID represents some variable that actual controller has to set. Since `@ControllerAdvice` is running before controller, how can I declare this variable and use it in Advice? If that's even possible.

Comment: I think you've answered your own question with "Since @ControllerAdvice is running before controller" - is there no way you can set the ModelAttribute in your ControllerAdvice, and reference it in the Controller?

Comment: I thought so. The point is, that I have to call a service and pass that specific variable, that is different for each controller and set a return result as model attribute in `@ControllerAdvice`.

Comment: @DaveyDaveDave I'm not sure you are right. Suppose you use the `@ControllerAdvice` to handle exceptions (as shown in the official examples), how can it be that he is run before? I guess that a `ControllerAdvice` is yet another controller that is available and is executed according to the annotations provided to the methods (e.g. `@ExceptionHandling` or `@ModelAttribute`)

Answer (score 0):

I think a better solution would been using some kind of abstract-class-pattern for your controller

```
public abstract class AbstractController {

    @ModelAttribute
    public void globalAttributes(Model model) {
       model.addAttribute("pageId", getPageId());
    }

    abstract String getPageId();
}

public class MyController extends AbstractController {

    @Override
    public String getPageId() {
       return "MyPageID"
    }

    //..your controller methods
}
```

Comment: Yup, I already have that solution, but wanted to check if I can accomplish the same using `@ControllerAdvice` :) thanks

Comment: @Alchnemesis: The Spring-Reference for the current Version 4.2.3 does not have any hint that one could get any information about the method that (will/has) handled the request. - so then answer is: no you can not